# Paste or Insert Text anywhere at cursor position on a windows system with a background C# Application

Tags: c#, .net, copy-paste, hotkeys

I like to write a small Application to paste/insert some text at my current cursor position.

**For Example**: I am in Word: Here I like to press CTRL+ALT+1 and it will insert some text at my pointer position. Or I have an open Internet-Explorer window, Notepad, Adobe, ..., or any other application

I started with listening the shortcuts with a [global Keyboard hook library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook).

And the event for the hotkeys is working fine for me. But now I got stuck because I found no way to paste/insert the text at the position from my cursor. I tried using **SendMessage/PostMessage**, or **SendKeys**.

The problem with SendMessage is that I was not able to get every window and SendKeys is fired multiple times if you are using it togheter with the Keyboard hook library...

Any ideas how I could continue?

**Code for the Hotkeys:**

```
namespace Developper_Dashboard
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();

        private bool IsADown = false;
        private bool IsBDown = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Hide the MainForm
            this.Opacity = 0;

            // Listening Keys
            gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.LControlKey);
            gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.LMenu);
            gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.NumPad1);
            gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);
            gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);
        }

        void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LControlKey)
            {
                IsADown = false;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LMenu)
            {
                IsBDown = false;
            }
            if (!IsADown | !IsBDown)
            {
                this.Opacity = 0;
            }
            //e.Handled = true;
        }

        void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LControlKey)
            {
                IsADown = true;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LMenu)
            {
                IsBDown = true;
            }
            if (IsADown && IsBDown)
            {
                this.Opacity = 1;
            }
            if (IsADown && IsBDown && e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
            {
                // Here the code for paste/insert...?
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to write it yourself, or are you just after the functionality? If the latter, then checkout http://www.autohotkey.com which can be configured to do what you want.

Comment: "...and SendKeys is fired multiple times if you are using it togheter with the Keyboard hook library... "  I noticed you have commented out "e.Handled = true".  You have to cancel the keystrokes that fired the original combination before sending the "auto paste" keystrokes, otherwise the combination will still be "down" when you inject the new keystrokes.